# How high is high I/O for SQL Server 2005?

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have a RAID 1 setup averaging 40 - 60 I/Os per disk and 0.5 average disk queue length. According to [BOL example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc966540.aspx) below, this is not a bottleneck.

> Disk Reads/sec            80
> Disk Writes/sec           70
> Avg. Disk Queue Length    5
>
> In that case, you are encountering (80 + (2 * 70))/2 = 110 I/Os per disk and your disk queue length = 5/2 = 2.5 which indicates a border line I/O bottleneck.

Which brings me to my question, how high is a high I/O? The average disk queue length is quite well documented in that it should not exceed 2 per CPU but BOL makes no mention about I/Os per disk?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quick clarification... "The average disk queue length is quite well documented in that it should not exceed 2 per CPU" should be "The average disk queue length is quite well documented in that it should not exceed 2 per spindle", but that common knowledge is not neccessarily true.

More information on this topic from the Microsoft SQL support team here: http://blogs.msdn.com/psssql/archive/2007/02/21/sql-server-urban-legends-discussed.aspx

As I read your question, you want to know how many IOPS (IO's per second) is high for a hard drive.  The answer is "when you have more than the drive supports".  a 15K Seagate Cheetah supports many more IOPS than a 5400 RPM laptop drive.  In your case, you have the drives setup as RAID 1 (which adds redundancy, but reduces the available IOPS as you write the same data twice).

Courtesy of Wikipedia (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IOPS), some standard numbers:

- 7200RPM SATA drives - ~90 IOPS
- 10kRPM Serial Attached SCSI drives - ~ 140 IOPS
- 15kRPM Serial Attached SCSI drives - ~180 IOPS
- Simple SLC SSD - ~400 IOPS
- Intel X-25 M (MLC; As of March 2009[update], no competition) - ~1,500 IOPS
- Intel X-25 E (SLC; As of March 2009[update], no competition) - ~5,000 IOPS (Intel's data sheet says 3,300 write, 35,000 read IOPS, while 5,000 are measured for a mix)
- ioDrive, a PCI-Express card with Flash - >80,000 IOPS
- DDRdrive X1, a May 2009 PCI Express based solid-state drive - 300,000+ (512B Random Read IOPS) and 200,000+ (512B Random Write IOPS)
- Violin Memory Appliance, 1,000,000+ Random Read IOPS

Answer (score 0):

The Disk Reads/Writes data in itself wouldn't (to me) make sense to have a specific high I/O defined, as hardware advances would render such things obsolete in short order. The key is looking for where things are causing delays, not simply what might be harmless but frequent disk activity.

[This](http://www.sql-server-performance.com/articles/audit/hardware_bottlenecks_p1.aspx) is a pretty good article on hardware bottlenecks for SQL Server

Answer (score 0):

Your disk manufacturer should provide info on the kind of IOPS you can expect to handle. Just as important as disk queue is sec/read and sec/write - anything more than 15-20ms sustained is probably gonna hurt.